# Timeout ignored by AspNet Identity and OWIN

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin

I hope someone can help me. We are writing an MVC app and we are using AspNet Identity and OWIN and we are trying to set the timeout to 4 hours. However, it seems like no matter what we set the timeout to the site times out in 30 minutes and we get redirected to the login page.

As an aside, this is an MVC app in EpiServer, but the mechanism for using AspNet Identity and OWIN is the same.

In our web.config, we have the following settings:

```
<authentication mode="None">
</authentication>
```

and

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="240" />
```

and, in appSettings,

```
<add key="SessionTimeout" value="240" />
```

In our OWIN startup class, we have the following code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        CookieAuthenticationProvider provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider();
        Action<CookieApplyRedirectContext> originalHandler = provider.OnApplyRedirect;

        provider.OnApplyRedirect = context =>
        {
            context.RedirectUri = $"{new PathString(Global.LoginPath)}/?session_expired=1";
            originalHandler.Invoke(context);
        };

        provider.OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager<PortalDirectApplicationUser>, PortalDirectApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(user));

        app.SetupPortalDirectAspNetIdentity<PortalDirectApplicationUser>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieName = "OurCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString(Global.LoginPath),
            Provider = provider,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeout"]))
        });
    }
}
```

So the timeout in the startup class is also 240 minutes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why the site times out in 30 minutes? I have searched for answers and I'm obviously not setting something correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "site times out"?

Comment: I get redirected to the login page. Session times out.

Comment: Does session really time out? or you just getting logged out? Because identity does not use session. Also 30 minutes matches your `SecurityStampValidator` setting. Do your users have any value in `SecurityStamp` field?

Comment: Agreed. We're getting logged out. And under my account, which I tested earlier, there is no Security Stamp.

Comment: Then you are getting logged out by `SecurityStampValidator` - just run `update [ApplicationUserTable] sert SecurityStamp = newId() where securitystamp is null` in your DB to get some value into this. Login again and check.

Comment: I did this for my user in the AspNetUsers table. It now has a security stamp. With the expiration set to 240 minutes and the validate set to 30 it still asks me to log in after 30 minutes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm.. then it is something else that does the logout. Just to be sure, try removing part from config related to `provider.OnValidateIdentity` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: It seems like it is working as expected, if I am to understand it right. I don't think it's timing out or logging me out. The expiration is set to 4 hours, however the validation interval was set to 30 minutes. That is when it's prompting for authentication. Since we don't want this behavior I just upped the value of the validate interval and it respects the expiration timeout.

Comment: Be careful with this one. You have set sliding expiration and 4 hours security stamp invalidation - these are for different purposes. SecurityStampInvalidator is to log out all user auth-cookies when a password is changed or account is disabled. If you set this value too high, you open yourself to security issue of user login cookies keep working, when the password have been changed (or even account does not exist anymore). So better sort this one out.